# Facebook problem + django

Tags: django, facebook

I am trying to write a facebook app where user can see the status history of his friends.
Everything seems to work fine until I try to save the status information in my DB.
here is code :

```
   class UserStatus(models.Model):
        facebookid = models.IntegerField()
        time = models.IntegerField()
        status_msg = models.CharField(max_length = 2000)



@facebook.require_login()
 def canvas(request):
    # Get the User object 
    user, created = FacebookUser.objects.get_or_create(id = request.facebook.uid)
    user_lastname = request.facebook.users.getInfo([request.facebook.uid], ['last_name'])[0]['last_name']
    query = "SELECT time,message FROM status WHERE uid=%s" % request.facebook.uid
    result = request.facebook.fql.query(query)
```

So result give me all the information of the status.
so my problem is its give error when I try to save it.

```
 userstatus = UserStatus()
  for item in result:
  userstatus.facebookid = request.facebook.uid
  userstatus.time = item.time


userstatus.msg = item.message
  userstatus.save()
```

error:
Errors while loading page from application

Received HTTP error code 500 while loading

So how can I fix this.

thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give more information. What is the exact error and traceback?

Comment: The problem is every time it gives this error:
Errors while loading page from application

Received HTTP error code 500 while loading http://taramsfb.tarams.com/facebook/

There are still a few kinks Facebook and the makers of fblaspal are trying to iron out. We appreciate your patience as we try to fix these issues. Your problem has been logged - if it persists, please come back in a few days. Thanks!
I am no idea where the problem is.

Comment: As long as the facebook app is in development mode, you should be able to do 'view source' in your browser on the error page and see the actual Django traceback (commented out).

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if you are getting results from this,

```
result = request.facebook.fql.query(query)
```

Make sure that the results are in correct format required by your model ( uid is integer, time is integer and message is string.

Again make sure that result is a valid python object and not a JSON string/Object.

Remember python is not fully compatible with JSON so if result is JSON then do this to convert it to python Object,

```
import simplejson
result = simpljson.loads(result) # if result was a JSON string
result = simpljson.loads(simplejson.dumps(result)) # if result was a JSON object
```

Check if now result is a list of dictionaries { "time" : 123456, "messaage": "xyz"}.

```
for item in result:
    userstatus = UserStatus() 
    userstatus.facebookid = request.facebook.uid
    userstatus.time = item["time"]
    userstatus.msg = item["message"]
    userstatus.save()
```

And you should not have any errors now.

Comment: StakcOverfolw TIP 1 : Always check the date of question before answering. :(